# Use a different measurement of data rather than KB

Tags: php

I'm currently tinkering around with some code which allows me to upload files to my site. I am going to set an option in a configuration file which allows users to set the maximum upload limit. At the moment this has to be entered in kilobytes and I was wondering whether or not it'd be possible to have it entered in MB?

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
**&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)** <---- Entered in Kilobytes, not MB.
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Comment: Yes, what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: It's entered in **bytes**

Comment: PHP's going to be providing that `['size']` parameter in bytes no matter what you do, so you'd have to take your config file value and convert it to bytes anyways, or take the php value and conver it to whatever units your config file uses. Which way you go is up to you.

Comment: If only there were preprocessor macros. Else, No. But, there are no macros in PHP!!

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$b = 1000000;
$kb = $b / 1024;
$mb = $kb / 1024;
if($_FILES['size']['size'] < $mb * 2) {
    // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to define a function to convert to MB to bytes, i.e.:

```
function MB($mb) {
   return $mb*1024*1024;
}
```

Then you can make your comparison like:

```
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < MB(2000))
```

Comment: And another one to convert bytes to kilobytes! We need more functions! For every math expression!

Comment: Oops - in his post he said kilobytes, I should have clued in.  Edited.

Comment: I meant that it's an overkill to create a function to encapsulate `* 1024 * 1024` maths.

Comment: `function isNull($null = null) { return is_null($null) }` basically represents how redundant it is to make a function for simple math :p

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    define('MB', 1024*1024);
    echo 10*MB;
?>
```

That's another way to do it.

Also, there are no macros in C. So, it's not possible like in C,C++ to `#define` these things.